# why is this an invalid conversion when the argument I am giving is an int

Tags: c++

This is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point
{
private: int x, y;
public:
   Point(int f = 0, int g = 0)
   {
      x = f;
      y = g;
   }
   int getX() const
   {
      return x;
   }
   int getY() const
   {
      return y;
   }
   void setX(const int new_x)
   {
      x = new_x;
   }
   void setY(const int new_y)
   {
      y = new_y;
   }
};
class PointArray
{
private:
   Point * loc;
   int len;
   public:
   PointArray()
   {
      len = 0;
      loc = new Point[0];
   }
   PointArray(const Point * points, const int size)
   {
      len = size;
      loc = new Point[len];
      for(int f = 0; f < len; f++)
         loc[f] = points[f];
   }
   PointArray(const PointArray& pv)
   {
      len = pv.len;
      loc = new Point[len];
      for(int f = 0; f < len; f++)
         loc[f] = pv.loc[f];
   }
   ~PointArray()
   {
      delete[] loc;
   }
   void resize(int n)
   {
      Point *loc1 = new Point[n];
      for(int f = 0; f < len && f < n; f++)
         loc1[f] = loc[f];
      len = n;
      delete[] loc;
      loc = loc1;
   }
   void pushBack(const Point &p)
   {
      resize(len+1);
      loc[len-1] = p;
   }
   void insert(const int pos, const Point &p)
   {
      resize(len+1);
      for(int f = len-1; f > pos; f--)
         loc[f] = loc[f-1];
      loc[pos] = p;
   }
   void remove(const int pos)
   {
      for(int f = pos; f < len-1; f++)
         loc[f] = loc[f+1];
      resize(len-1);
   }
   const int getSize() const
   {
      return len;
   }
   void clear()
   {
      resize(0);
   }
   Point * get(const int pos)
   {
      if (pos >= len)
         return NULL;
      else 
      {
         Point * x = new Point();
         *x = loc[pos];
         return x;
      }
   }
   const Point * get(const int pos) const
   {
      if (pos >= len)
         return NULL;
      else 
      {
         Point * x = new Point();
         *x = loc[pos];
         return x;
      }
   }
};
class Polygon
{
protected: 
   PointArray * loci; 
   int sides;
   static int N;
   public:
   Polygon(Point * loc, int len)
   {
      loci = new PointArray(loc, len);
      sides = len;
      N++;
   }
   Polygon(const PointArray& pv)
   {
      loci = new PointArray(pv);
      sides = pv.getSize();
      N++;
   }
   Polygon(const Polygon& pv)
   {
      loci = new PointArray(*pv.loci);
      sides = pv.sides;
      N++;
   } 
   ~Polygon()
   {
      delete loci;
      N--;
   }
   virtual double area() = 0;
   static int getNumPolygons()
   {
      return N;
   }
   int getNumSides()
   {
      return sides;
   }
   const PointArray * getPoints()
   {
      return loci;
   }
};
class Rectangle : public Polygon
{ 
private:
   typedef Polygon super;
   void makeRectangle(const Point e, const Point r)
   {
      Point * loci = new Point[4];
      loci[0] = e;
      loci[2] = r;
      loci[1] = new Point(e.getX(), r.getY());
      loci[3] = new Point(r.getX(), e.getY());
   }
   void makeRectangle (const int x1, const int x2, const int y1, const int y2)
   {
      Point * loci = new Point[4];
      loci[0] = new Point(x1, y1);
      loci[1] = new Point(x2, y1);
      loci[2] = new Point(x2, y2);
      loci[3] = new Point(x1, y2);
   }
};
```

The compiler is giving me these errors in the two overloaded makeRectangle() when they call the Point(int, int) constructor, saying:

```
geometry.cpp: In member function 'void Rectangle::makeRectangle(Point, Point)':
geometry.cpp:170:45: error: invalid conversion from 'Point*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
geometry.cpp:8:4: error: initializing argument 1 of 'Point::Point(int, int)' [-fpermissive]
geometry.cpp:171:45: error: invalid conversion from 'Point*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
geometry.cpp:8:4: error: initializing argument 1 of 'Point::Point(int, int)' [-fpermissive]
geometry.cpp: In member function 'void Rectangle::makeRectangle(int, int, int, int)':
geometry.cpp:176:33: error: invalid conversion from 'Point*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
geometry.cpp:8:4: error: initializing argument 1 of 'Point::Point(int, int)' [-fpermissive]
geometry.cpp:177:33: error: invalid conversion from 'Point*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
geometry.cpp:8:4: error: initializing argument 1 of 'Point::Point(int, int)' [-fpermissive]
geometry.cpp:178:33: error: invalid conversion from 'Point*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
geometry.cpp:8:4: error: initializing argument 1 of 'Point::Point(int, int)' [-fpermissive]
geometry.cpp:179:33: error: invalid conversion from 'Point*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
geometry.cpp:8:4: error: initializing argument 1 of 'Point::Point(int, int)' [-fpermissive]
```

Because x1, x2, y1, and y2 are integers and therefore should be compatible with the Point(int, int) constructor, I do not understand why it is giving me the error: "invalid conversion from 'Point*' to 'int'".

Comment: Way too much irrelevant code. Bottom line is that C++ isn't Java and you're doing too much allocating and raw pointer handling, and you're mixing pointers and values. Also, hidden `new[]`/`delete` mismatches aside from the compiler errors. I don't even know where to start pointing out things that are wrong.

Comment: For a start, `loci[0]` is a `Point` not a `Point *`, so you shouldn't `new` into it.

Comment: And which is line 170? It is important, when asking, to provide a problem statement that is as small and concise as possible, and to indicate both the error message en the location in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

> Getters and setters

Having getters and setters for the sake of having them is [never a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters-accessors/12108025#12108025). Therefore your code for `Point` can be reduced to:

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Which not only is easier and faster to read, but is just as constant correct as your solution was.

---

> The array

Your `PointArray` class is less than reusable. You can use standard containers instead. Your `PointArray` class can be reduced to:

```
using PointArray = std::vector<Point>;
```

---

> The Polygon base class

The `Polygon` class can also be improved. First of all you don't need `loci` to be dynamically allocated. You should use:

```
class Polygon {
protected: 
   PointArray loci; 
   int sides;
   static int N;
```

Now, for the constructor you could use the following instead of the C-style array that you are expecting from the first constructor:

```
public:
   Polygon(const PointArray& loc) {
      loci = loc
      sides = loc.size();
      N++;
   }
```

As you can see there's no need for the `len` argument. You could also use an `std::initializer_list` to allow expressions like:

```
Polygon x { Point(...), Point(...), Point(...), ... };
```

And here's how:

```
    Polygon(const std::initializer_list<Point> list)
        : loci(list)
        , sides(list.size())
        { N++; }
```

And after your smart edit you can get rid of the custom copy constructor and destructor, effectively following the [Rule of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/).

The rest is pretty much the same:

```
    virtual double area() = 0;
    static int getNumPolygons() { return N; }
    int getNumSides() { return sides; }
```

except for `getPoints`. I'd suggest two different overloads: `const` and non-`const`:

```
    PointArray& getPoints() { return loci; }
    const PointArray& getPoints() const { return loci; }
};
```

---

> The Rectangle class

And finally your rectangle class can, of course, be improved:

```
class Rectangle : public Polygon { 
private:
    void makeRectangle(const Point& e, const Point& r) {
        loci.push_back(e);
        loci.push_back(r);
        loci.emplace_back(e.x, r.y);
        loci.emplace_back(r.x, e.y);
    }

    void makeRectangle (const int x1, const int x2, const int y1, const int y2) {
        loci.emplace_back(x1, y1);
        loci.emplace_back(x2, y1);
        loci.emplace_back(x2, y2);
        loci.emplace_back(x1, y2);
    }
};
```

---

> Conclusion

After this simple refactoring, all your errors should be gone and your code should be much shorter and readable.